# <Subject> were <clarification> is this correct?

Tags: sentence, syntactic-analysis

Is it correct to use 'were' to clarify usage in the following sentence:

"Model A is a combination of model B and C were model B is used for (..)"

to clarify "were" model B is used for in the combination.

Or should this be "where" or is even "were" to explain completely wrong?

Thanks,

Comment: Hi, jos, and welcome to EL&U. Is the sentence you are quoting something you found in a book or other published item? If so, I'm pretty sure that _were_ is simply a typo for _where_. If, instead, the quoted sentence is your own creation, I have trouble following what you're saying (or asking)—particularly in line 3. Please consider rewording the question to make clearer what the issue you want to resolve is.

Answer (score 1):

The word "were" must be a typo or mistake. The only way that sentence makes sense is for it to be "where".

> Model A is a combination of model B and C **where** model B is used for (..)

Comment: I would go further and say that it makes sense to use 'whereas' in this sentence, as it is a comparative phrase

Answer (score 0):

It could conceivably be  *Model A is a combination of models B and C were model B to be used for...*, though this is unlikely.  I would agree with others that, without context, the likeliest explanation is a typo for *where*.